# Error: Thread creation failed-Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have deployed my Rails application on server.

It is working fine, but it crashed on sign_up page and server will be stop.

I Checked my mongrel.log file, it give the following error.

libgomp: Thread creation failed: Cannot allocate memory

How can I resolved this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your system was out of memory.  You're probably on a VM with a limited amount of memory (and no swap).  You'll need to get more memory, or use less.